# Width of $\eta$ meson mass peak?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, experimental-physics, particle-detectors

> In an experiment an $\eta$ meson is produced with total energy $E _ { 0 } = 2000$ MeV in the laboratory frame.
>   Estimate the width of the $\eta$ mass peasured in a calorimeter that has an energy and angular
>   resolution of $\sigma _ { E } / E = 5 \%$ and $\sigma _ { \theta } = 0.05$ radians, respectively.

So, I have got an answer for $\dfrac{\delta m}{m} \approx 9.5 \%$ but I am not sure if that's the thing the question is asking. I mean, to get the mass peak, do I have to multiply the $\dfrac{\delta m}{m}$ by the mass of the $\eta$ meson, or is $\dfrac{\delta m}{m}$ only is the final answer the question is asking for.

I am confused about what the final answer should look like i.e is it $\delta m$ or $\dfrac{\delta m}{m}$?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

$\delta m$ is the width of the peak. This is a good approximation because the natural width of the $\eta$ resonance is ~keV so can be ignored.

The shape of any resonance peak is best described the convolution of the lineshape with the resolution function. If one is much narrower than the other, it can be ignored (equivalently, it can be treated as a delta function).

Comment: What is the formula for the FWHM? So does it mean in this case, the answer would be just $\delta m$ or FWHM which is $2.35 \times \delta m$?

Comment: Presumably the original quantity $\sigma_E$ is a standard deviation, and you propagated that through.

Comment: Yes, it was propagated through.So, technically, the final answer would be $\delta m$ instead of $\frac{\delta m}{m}$?